# Convert Tauri File-Drop Event into a real File

Tags: file, events, form-data, tauri

I am using Tauri with the js api. I am trying to get the file I drop into the window, I used the File-Drop event but it returns an event and I need to convert it to a real file, because I am trying to send the file to an API and I use a formData to format it.

Answer (score 0):

Lorix.  I know this is old, but I think I found a solution for myself so I wanted to share for future searchers.

Firstly, make sure the window you are trying to drop a file onto is configured in the `tauri.conf.json` with a key-value of `"fileDropEnabled": true`. And be sure that you've installed the tauri api on the frontend:
`npm install @tauri-apps/api`

Then, on the front end, you need to listen for the `tauri://file-drop` event using the API.
That import for me looked like this:
`import { listen } from '@tauri-apps/api/event'`

Then somewhere within your front-end logic, you need to await the event using the `listen` api function:

```
  import { listen } from '@tauri-apps/api/event';

  await listen("tauri://file-drop", async (e) => {
    // event handling logic
  })
```

The resulting event is an object with the following shape(TypeScript):

```
{
  id: number,
  event: string,
  windowLabel: string,
  payload: string[],
}
```

where `payload` is an array of paths to all the files that the event registered on drop.